# How to retain the 'New' constructor across subclasses?

Tags: vb.net

Let's start with an example Module:

```
Module PuppyKillers
    Public Puppies As Double = 135
    Public SquadSize As Integer = 5
    Class PuppyKiller
        Private KillingTimer As New System.Timers.Timer _
            With {.AutoReset = True, .Interval = 1000, .Enabled = False}
        Public PuppiesPerSecond As Double = 0.5
        Public name As String = "John Doe"
        Public Sub New(Optional param As Double = 1)
            PuppiesPerSecond = PuppiesPerSecond * param
            AddHandler KillingTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf KillPuppies
        End Sub
        Private Sub KillPuppies(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
            If Puppies <= 0 Then
                Me.Killing = False
            Else
                Puppies -= PuppiesPerSecond
            End If
        End Sub

        Property Killing As Boolean
            Get
                Return KillingTimer.Enabled
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                KillingTimer.Enabled = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class

    Class ChiefPuppyKiller
        Inherits PuppyKiller
    End Class

    Sub Exterminators_Start() ' 4 Killers + 1 Chief
        Dim squad As New ArrayList

        REM The following line prevents the compilation.
        squad.Add(New ChiefPuppyKiller(3)) 'A chief kills 3 times the normal amount.

        For i As Integer = 1 To SquadSize - 1
            squad.Add(New PuppyKiller)
        Next

        REM Start the slaughter
        Console.WriteLine("Puppies: " & Puppies)
        For Each c As PuppyKiller In squad
            c.Killing = True
        Next
        Do
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(4737)
            Console.WriteLine("Remaining Puppies: " & Math.Ceiling(Puppies))

            Application.DoEvents()
            If Puppies = 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Meow: No more puppies.")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

I've a problem with the above block of code: I cannot find a way to use `PuppyKiller`'s Constructor from its subclasses: `ChiefPuppyKiller` in this case.

I got an error about the number of parameters for the constructor, so I assume that the base class constructor is not used.

I don't want to declare a new `New` sub for every subclass. But I'd like to be able to specify the puppy killing multiplier in the constructor.

---

*Note: no animal has been harmed while writing this question, as the code does not compile.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to add a new constructor for every class where you want to pass that value in:

```
Class ChiefPuppyKiller
  Inherits PuppyKiller

  Public Sub New(param As Double)
    MyBase.New(param)
  End Sub
End Class
```